# setSlicerState() with Tuple slicer not working/supported? "filters property is invalid"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I can't seem to find a solid answer anywhere if setSlicerFilter() method in javascript for power bi embedded reports supports filterType 6 (tuple) - one post suggests it does not but nothing official.

setSlicerState() is working fine for other types (basic and relativeDate) but returns an error with Tuple specifically: "filters property is invalid"

Below is the state object that i am passing to the setSlicerState() method (which was originally retrieved from the getSlicerState() method, so i believe it's format is just fine)

Getting from slicer with getSlicerState()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the out-of-the-box hierarchy and tuple slicers aren't supported with powerbi-client.

**Reference:**

[Use slicers when embedding a report in Power BI embedded analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers#limitations)